# Find if string contains multiple different substrings

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looping through a text document to assign URLs to a downloader. If the URL contains certain paths (e.g., `/channels/`) it needs to be assigned different set of settings before it is downloaded.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (batch.txt) do (
    echo %%A|find "/channel/"|find "/user/"
    if errorlevel 0 echo %%A
    else if echo %%A|find "/watch?"
    if errorlevel 0 echo %%A
    else if echo %%A|find "/playlist?"
    if errorlevel 0 echo %%A
    else echo FAIL
)
```

This is not working and is echoing every line of my file. I know my `if else` structure is wrong but I do not know the correct syntax. I also need to ignore lines that start with `#`. How can I do this?

Comment: The `else` keyword has to be on the same line as the closing `)` of the mandatory code block `if condition (...) else ...` See [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56820987.txt"

FOR /f "tokens=*eol=#" %%a IN (%filename1%) DO (
 ECHO %%a|FIND "/channel/" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO found "/channel/" IN %%a
 ECHO %%a|FIND "/watch?" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO found "/watch?" IN %%a
 ECHO %%a|FIND "/playlist?" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO found "/playlist?" IN %%a

)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q56820987.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Apart from the faulty if/else syntax, `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0. So is `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0`, except that the former can be used within a block but the latter cannot.